# How to get a keySet of HashMap filter by boolean value in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

```
Map map = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
map.keySet(); // filtering the true value
```

Comment: There is no built-in method for that. You need to write your own code which will iterate over all map entries, check what value entry holds and based on that value decide if you want to store entry key in set.

Answer (score 3):

You can `filter` over the `entrySet` and then use `map` to only obtain the keys with streams.

```
Set<Long> resultKeys = map.entrySet().stream().filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/7DUNPL)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.  You're filtering the `Map.Entry` on the value and then mapping the `entry` to the `key`.

```
Map<Long, Boolean> map =
        Map.of(1L, true, 2L, false, 3L, true, 4L, false);
Set<Long> set = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(Entry::getValue).map(Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(set);
```

Prints

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the map's entry set, and add the `key` to a set if the `value` is `true`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Long, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>(); 
    map.put(1l,true); map.put(2l,false); map.put(3l,true);
    Set<Long> validKeys = getValidKeys(map);
    System.out.println(validKeys);
}
private static Set<Long> getValidKeys(Map<Long, Boolean> map) {
    Set<Long> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(Map.Entry<Long, Boolean> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue()) set.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    return set;
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 3]
```